# how to correct the error "wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0" on sdl2::render::Canvas

Tags: rust

I am testing SDL2 under rust and I have written a function that is supposed to load an image how can I load my image and not have the following error "wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
" on the second parameter of my function?

```
 fn load_image(dtLoad: &str, canva: sdl2::render::Canvas) -> sdl2::render::Canvas {

    let _img_load = {
        let _x = match canva.texture_creator() {
            Ok(_x) => _x, 
            Err(_) => panic!("Error create canva"),
        };
        let _load = match _x.load_texture(dtLoad) {
            Ok(_load) => _load,
            Err(_) => panic!("Error load texture\t:{}", dtLoad),
        };
        canva.copy(&_load, None, None);
    };
    return _img_load;
}
```

I expect the function to load images with SDL Image into an `SDL_Surface` and return them to the caller. Except I get this error message:

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0
 --> src/main.rs:4:60
  |
4 | fn load_image(dtLoad: &str, canva: sdl2::render::Canvas) -> sdl2::render::Canvas {
  |                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected 1 type argument
```

Comment: you seem to be specifying a return type but not returning anything

Comment: even if I send back _img_load which is supposed to be the right type I still have the same mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`sdl2::render::Canvas`](https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.32.2/sdl2/render/struct.Canvas.html) is defined as (as one can see in the documentation I linked):

```
struct Canvas<T: RenderTarget> { /* fields omitted */ }
```

This means it is generic over a `T`. As such you cannot use `sdl2::render::Canvas` just like that as it isn't a full type yet. You have to supply a generic parameter like `sdl2::render::Canvas<WindowContext>`. Without more context we cannot help you more than that.

---

Apart from that, some general hints:

- Please use standard Rust formatting, including spacing and line breaks. You can use `rustfmt` to easily format your code. At the very least, format your code with `rustfmt` before asking on StackOverflow. You can use [the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) to format your code with `rustfmt`. I edited your question to fix this.
- It is a very bad idea to start all variable names with `_` as this disables unused variable warnings. Those warnings have a purpose. And even if you don't like those warnings, rather use `#![allow(unused_variable)]` instead of adding an underscore to each variable name. To be clear: I still **do not recommend** ignoring these warnings!
- `return` should be omitted in Rust when possible. In your case it's the last statement so just write `img_load`.
- Please at least try to make your StackOverflow question readable by formatting your code and error message. If you don't care, you can't expect others to care.

Comment: Indeed, you are right and it works, thank you very much and I will try to be more careful next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

The context is not very clear here, but from what is given it seems `Canvas` is a generic type and thus should be supplied a type on which it's going to be specialised (implicit template specialisation).

So `Canvas` probably is similar to: `struct Canvas<T> { .. }`

To use it either your function needs to be a template or `Canvas` needs to take a type parameter for it's template:

```
fn load_image<T>(... Canvas<T>)-> Canvas<T> where T: ...{
```

or

```
fn load_image(... Canvas<SomeSpecificType>)-> Canvas<SomeSpecificType> {
```

The call site (probably in `main` from the {unformatted and difficult to follow - please use some formatting} error message) then should instantiate `Canvas` accordingly:

```
let c = Canvas<SomeSpecificType> {  ... };
```